# Write multiple cells at once in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA I am using some code to update the cells. Like:

```
for i = 1 to 1000
    for j = 1 to 1000
        cells(j,i)=<whatever_different_in_each_cell>
    next
next
```

Is there a way to update all cells at once, instead of updating each cell individually ? Reason is that updating one cell in Excel is time consuming and when there are many of them, then it quickly becomes endless.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Because you have cells adjacent to one another the array method as pointed out by Comintem is a great way to proceed.  If you wind up jumping all over the map err worksheet or multiple worksheets then you may want to do something like turn screen updating off until your code has done what it needs to do.  Then turn it back on at the end.

Comment: Comintern's solution works like a charm, thanks !! You may want to post it as real solution ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Range(<...>).Value = Array (value1, value2, <...>, valueN)
```

The number of values must be exactly the same as the number of cells in the `Range`, otherwise, the range will be filled with `#VALUE!`s.

Answer (score 0):

range(cells(1,1),cells(1000,1000))="whatever"

Comment: Thanks, but my whatever was between brackets to indicate that the cells may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub WriteMultipleCells()

x = "whatever"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:X1") = x

End Sub
```